# Verify client certificate using SSLServer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, client, certificate

Heres the code I'm using to setup the server:

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

socket = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 4433)

ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()
ssl_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("ssl/server/server.crt"))
ssl_context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("ssl/server/server.key"))

ca_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("ssl/ca/ca.crt"))

ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new(socket, ssl_context)

Thread.start(ssl_socket.accept) do |s|
    puts "Connected to #{s.peeraddr.last}"

    if s.peer_cert.verify(ca_cert.public_key)
        puts "Certificate verified"
    else
        puts "Certificate invalid"
    end
end
```

And the client:

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

socket = TCPSocket.new('127.0.0.1', 4433)

ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ssl_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("ssl/client1/client1.crt"))
ssl_context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("ssl/client1/client1.key"))

ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, ssl_context)

ca_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("ssl/ca/ca.crt"))

ssl_socket.connect

if ssl_socket.peer_cert.verify(ca_cert.public_key)
    puts "Certificate checks out"
else
    puts "Certificate not verified"
end
```

However, the server throws an exception when it tries to get the peer_cert that it cannot find.  Is there a way to get the SSLServer to expect a client certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [test_client_auth](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/openssl/test_ssl.rb#L110) and [start_server](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/openssl/utils.rb#L242) in the tests for `OpenSSL::SSL`.

From the top of my head, the only thing I see missing in your code is that you forgot to explicitly require client authentication on the server side - it is important to set the flag combination

```
flags = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER|OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT
ctx.verify_mode = flags
```

so that the server will actually *require* client authentication and not silently accept requests that come unauthenticated. If you don't set these, the server will be happy without requesting client authentication and as a result there will also be no peer certificate available.

Comment: Does VERIFY_PEER also mean that the manual verification in the question is now unnecessary?