# How to manage encryption key in a Ruby application which stores encrypted user credentials on the hard drive?

Tags: ruby, linux, authentication, encryption, command-line-interface

I have an command line application (not rails) that needs the user to provide their username and password for the website the cli accesses.

I don't want to make the user enter their details for each and every command they execute.

How do I store the details without compromising security and storing the details without encryption? If I encrypt the password, where should I store the pass key so it is still secure?

I imagine an implementation similar to the way the Heroku gem works would be good.

UPDATE:

So I have gone ahead and implemented this in my application, but something doesn't feel quite right about the solution yet.

Prior to accessing the website for the first time, the user is prompted to enter their username and password. Following successful login, the user is asked whether to store the details for later. If yes, the password is encrypted using a key - however, as this is a ruby gem, the key is stored in the application in plain text.

Is there another way to do this. The file containing the username/password is now secure BUT the key to unlock it is stored in the application code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735422/verify-client-certificate-using-sslserver-in-ruby

Comment: I dont understand how this is relevant, my app simply needs to store and retrieve username and password in a safe way?

Comment: I was thinking that suggesting a password protected certificate auth would solve your security concerns, that is similar to heroku gem. Good thing it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Hi Clyfe, perhaps you could outline your answer in a little more detail, from what I understand I would need to have control of the website - which I don't have.

Comment: Yes, this would need server coding too.

Comment: I dont have access to the server - the command line app scapes content from a website - the user needs to provide credentials to access the content.

Answer (score 0):

On the update: no. If you need access to the plain text password, you can only obfuscate the password. You cannot safely store it. The key needs to be in plain, or the key that encrypts that key needs to be in plain, ad infinity. Can't be done.