# How can I implement custom verification of an SSL certificate in Ruby's SSLServer?

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I'm using SSL to form a trusted connection between two peers. Each peer knows who it expects to be connecting to (or accepting a connection from) at a given time. It should only accept valid certificates, and further, it should only accept certificates with certain attributes (probably by checking the canonical name).

So far, I can get the two sides to talk, based on [the example in this question, and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735422/verify-client-certificate-using-sslserver-in-ruby). Each side can print out the certificate presented by the other peer.

I'm not sure what the correct way to verify these certificates is, though. The obvious way would be to just look at the certificates after the connection is made and drop the connection if it doesn't meet our expectations.

Is there a more correct way to do this? Is there a callback which is given the peer's presented certificate and can give it a thumbs-up or thumbs-down? Or is the right thing to handle it after SSL is done with its work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, I am the CA, so trusting the CA isn't an issue. I'm
>   signing these certificates on behalf of my users. The canonical names
>   aren't even domain names. Users connect peer-to-peer. I want the
>   client software I distribute to verify that the connecting user has a
>   certificate I signed and is the right user.

Its sounds like you are running a Private PKI. Just load the root of the trust chain into OpenSSL with `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` or `SSL_load_verify_locations`.

Be sure to use `SSL_PEER_VERIFY` to ensure OpenSSL performs the verification. The call would probably look like `SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);`. If peer validation fails, then the `connect` will fail.

There are ways to ensure the `connect` succeeds and then catching the error later. The trick is to set the verify callback, have the verify callback always return `1`, and then call `SSL_get_verify_result` after the connection is setup. See [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) for an example.

**Note**: in all cases, you still have to perform name checking manually. OpenSSL currently does not do it (its in HEAD for OpenSSL 1.1.0). See `libcurl` or PostgreSQL for some code you can rip.

An example of a SSL/TLS client is provided by OpenSSL at its wiki. See [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client). There's no server code or example at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what the correct way to verify these certificates is, though.
>   The obvious way would be to just look at the certificates after the
>   connection is made and drop the connection if it doesn't meet our
>   expectations.

There's a lot to this, and some of it is not obvious. I'm going to break the answer up into parts, but all the parts try to answer your question.

---

First, you can verify the certificates are well formed. The group responsible in the context of the Web is the CA/Browser forums. They have baseline and extended requirements for creating certificates:

- Baseline Certificate Requirements, https://www.cabforum.org/Baseline_Requirements_V1_1_6.pdf
- Extended Validation Certificate Requirements, https://www.cabforum.org/Guidelines_v1_4_3.pdf

In the baseline docs, you will find, for example, an IP listed as the Common Name (CN) must also be listed in the Subject Alternate Names (SAN). In the extended docs, you will find that private IPs (Reserved per RFC 1918) cannot be present in a extended validation (EV) certificate; and EV certificates cannot contain wild cards.

---

Second, you can perform customary validation according to RFC 5280, *Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile*, http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt.

The customary checks are the ones like hostname matching, time period validity checks, and verifying an end-entity or leaf certificate (client or server certificate) chains back to a root. In browsers using CAs, that's any number of hundreds of trusted roots or intermediates.

*If* you choose to perform revocation checking, then you will probably DoS your application (how is that for obvious!). A mobile client on a 3G network cannot download and process a 30MB CRL - it will surely hang the application. And an application cannot perform a OCSP query when the URL is wrong - that will surely fail.

Also, if you are performing hostname matching that includes wildcards, then care must be taken to handle ccTLDs properly. ccTLDs are like *.eu, *.us, or இலங்கை (nic.lk). There's some 5000 or so of them and Mozilla offers a list at http://publicsuffix.org/ (alternately, https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1).

---

Third, CAs don't warrant anything, so the answers you get from a CA is worthless. If you don't believe me, then check their Certification Practice Statement (CPS). For example, here is an excerpt from Apple's [Certification Authority Certification Practice Statement](https://ssl.apple.com/certificateauthority/pdf/Apple_AAI_CPS_v4.0.pdf) (18 Sept 2013, page 6):

```
2.4.1. Warranties to Subscribers
The AAI Sub-CA does not warrant the use of any Certificate to any Subscriber.

2.4.2. CA disclaimers of warranties
To the extent permitted by applicable law, Subscriber agreements, if applicable,
disclaim warranties from Apple, including any warranty of merchantability or
fitness for a particular purpose
```

That means that they don't warrant the binding of the public key to the organization through the issuer's signature. And that's the whole purpose of X509!.

---

Fourth, DNS does not provide authentic answers. So you might get a bad answer from DNS and happily march over to a server controlled by your adversary. Or, 10 of the 13 root DNS servers under US control may collude to give you a wrong answer in the name of US national security.

Trying to get an authentic response from a non-US server is near impossible. The "secure DNS" pieces (sans DNSSEC) are still evolving, and I'm not aware of any mainstream implementations.

In the case of colluding US servers, a quorum won't work because the US holds an overwhelming majority.

---

The problem here is that you are making security decisions based on input from external services (CA and DNS). Essentially, you are conferring too must trust in untrustworthy actors.

A great treatment of the problems with PKI and PKIX is Dr. Peter Gutmann's *Engineering Security* at www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf. Be sure to read Chapters 1 adn 6. Dr. Gutmann has a witty sense of humor, so its not dry reading. Another great book is Ross Anderson's *Security Engineering* at http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html.

---

You have a couple of defenses with all the problems caused by PKI, PKIX, and CAs. First, you can run a private PKI where you are your own certificate authority. In this case, you are not trusting an outsider. Bad DNS answers and rogue servers should be caught because the server's certificate will not form a valid chain.

Second, you can employ a security diversification strategy. Gutmann writes about it in his *Engineering Security* book, and you should visit "Security through Diversity" starting on page 292 and the "Risk Diversification for Internet Applications" section on page 296.

Third, you can employ a Trust-On-First-Use (TOFU) or Key Continuity strategy. This is similar to Wendlandt, Anderson and Perrig's *Perspectives: Improving SSH-style Host Authentication with Multi-Path Probing* or SSH's `StrictHostKeyChecking` option. In this strategy, you do the customary checks and then pin the certificate or public key. You can also ask for other's view of the certificate or public key. Unexpected certificate or key changes should set off alarm bells.

OWASP has an treatment of Certificate and Public Key Pinning at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning. Note: some places rotate their certificates every 30 days or so, so you should probably pin public keys if possible. The list of frequent rotators includes Google, and its one of the reasons tools like Certificate Patrol makes so much noise.

Comment: There's some great stuff in here, but I'm not quite seeing how it answers the question. In this case, I *am* the CA, so trusting the CA isn't an issue. I'm signing these certificates on behalf of my users. The canonical names aren't even domain names. Users connect peer-to-peer. I want the client software I distribute to verify that the connecting user has a certificate I signed and is the right user.

Comment: Hi Peeja. "I am the CA" - in this case, you are running a Private PKI. Just load the root of the trust chain into OpenSSL with `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` or `SSL_load_verify_locations`. Be sure to use `SSL_PEER_VERIFY` to ensure OpenSSL performs the verification. The call would probably look like `SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);`. If peer validation fails, then the `connect` will fail. **Note**: you still have to perform name checking manually. OpenSSL currently does not do so (its in HEAD for OpenSSL 1.1.0).

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was trying to figure out. If you post that as a separate answer, I'll accept it.