# Linux command line for ssl server?

Tags: linux, ssl, command-line-interface

I always use the socket command line tool to do quick socket tests for programs I'm writing.  http://w21.org/jnickelsen/socket/

I was wondering if there was a similar command line tool to set up a quick ssl socket client/server to test things.

### Edit: Easy Answer

So to make it easy on people who may wonder the same thing:

**If you want to be a client use openssl's s_client:**

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port
```

**If you want to be a server use openssl's s_server:**

```
openssl s_server -accept <port> -key <keyfile> -cert <certfile>
```

**Quick And Dirty cert and key for the server to use for testing:**

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa -keyout keyfile.key -out certfile.crt
```

Comment: This is not a single command but a way to setup in Ruby:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735422/verify-client-certificate-using-sslserver-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick SSL Client:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port>
```

Quick SSL Server:

```
openssl s_server -accept <port>
```

Comment: Found these after my question.  The server end is a little more complicated.  I was hoping it would just have a default certificate that it would use, but it didn't, so I had to self sign my own.

Comment: The manpage is at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_server.html . There are lots of options.